# Allocation function with a non-throwing exception specification

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, c++14

3.7.4.1[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/3 has the following sentence:

> If an allocation function declared with a non-throwing
>   *exception-specification* (15.4) fails to allocate storage, it shall
>   return a null pointer.

I don't know exactly what this sentence is trying to convey, as the two allocation functions shown in §3.7.4/2 (see below) don't have exception specifications.

> `void* operator new(std::size_t);`
>   `void* operator new[](std::size_t);`

And AFAICT, if I replace `operator new`, with one containing an *exception-specification*, in global scope, the code will not compile.

Comment: I think it is referring to the overloads of `new` that take a `nothrow_t` as an additional parameter. Instead of throwing a `bad_alloc` if they fail, they return `nullptr`.

Comment: I'm terrible with this type of language standard stuff, but this may be referring to overloads using `std::nothrow_t`. Those are marked with an exception-specification and return `nullptr` on failure.

Comment: But yeah, I'm not sure it's valid behavior to allow a `throw()/noexcept` specification on the regular `operator new/new[]` overload you have here. It should be valid (and often expected) for placement new and nothrow overloads, and in those cases, they "shall return a null pointer".

Comment: @JamesRoot @Ike From §17.6.4.6/2 (2.2) it seems to me that `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` does not have an exception-specification.

Comment: @JamesRoot @Ike I've just found the `nothrow` versions of `operator new` in §18.6/1 and contrary to what I said above, they have the exception-specification `noexcept`.

Comment: @Belloc Eek, that's confusing. nothrow new, by design, should never throw, so omitting `noexcept ` here just seems sloppy. Placement new may or may not throw. Vanilla new should succeed or throw. Need the lawyer to really solidify this (I'm just talking about the design part and how things should work), but I think the docs are referring to nothrow and placement new specifically, where they're allowed, by design, to return `nullptr` on failure.

Comment: @Ike See my prior comment.

Comment: @Belloc In particular, among these, placement new can go either way -- it may or may not throw. So perhaps the paragraph is referring to overloads of placement new, where the `noexcept` solidifes that, by design, the function shall return `nullptr` on failure.

Comment: @Ike `So perhaps the paragraph is referring to overloads of placement new, where the noexcept solidifes that, by design, the function shall return nullptr on failure.` I'll accept this as an answer, Thanks.

Comment: Best to be a little reluctant -- I'm far from a language lawyer. But that may be a hint to kind of investigate further. I'm mainly offering a perspective from the side of one used to overloading and using these operators, and how they are generally intended to be used and implemented.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - your first quote seems very clear. It covers functions with exception specifications.  The two functions you mention after do not have exception specifications, therefore they are not covered by your first quote.  Replacement of global `operator new` is covered by `[new.delete.single]`. Are you actually asking why `void* operator new(std::size_t) noexcept;` does not compile?

Comment: @M.M For me §3.7.4.1/3 was not about the placement forms functions **yet**, as these functions were not presented in §3.7.4/2. But Ike has already made it clear to me, that §3.7.4.1/3 is referring to all allocation functions in the library.